# implement a tuple with each element asscoaited with a name in C# VS2013

Tags: c#, dictionary, tuples

I need to implement a

```
       Dictionary<int, Tuple<string, double, double>>
```

in C# in VS2013.

The dictionary holds

```
       Dictionary<3, Tuple<"id1", 65.97, 9.8>>
```

I need to give a name for each element in the tuple. For example,

```
       Dictionary<3, Tuple<id:id1, value1:65.97, value2:9.8>>
```

I need to search an element in the tuple by their name to get its value.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why Tuple? Go far anonymous/strong types if you want names.

Comment: `Tuple` is a type that specifically doesn't have names by design.

Comment: If you need to give it a name, why not just make a class instead of using a Tuple..? That's what classes are for. Or a struct.

Comment: Vote for this feature there: https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/6257234-intellisense-for-tuples

Answer (score 1):

Define a Class and use that instead of a tuple.

```
public class ObjectName {
  public string id { get; set; }
  public double value1 { get; set; }
  public double value2 { get; set; }

  public ObjectName(string id, double val1, double val2) {
    this.id = id;
    this.value1 = val1;
    this.value2 = val2;
  }
}
```

Then in your code:

```
Dictionary<3, new ObjectName("id1", 65.97, 9.8 }>
```

Comment: Avoid mutable structs. This should be a class.

Comment: @Blorgbeard ...Where was it mutated?

Comment: Nowhere in the code that's shown, but it's *mutable* - it has public non-readonly fields.

Comment: Updated the code to use a class. Also added getters and setters, if you want a property to be read-only, just remove `set;` from the property definition.

Answer (score 1):

Go with this:

```
public sealed class MyTuple : IEquatable<MyTuple>
{
    private readonly string _Id; 
    private readonly double _Value1; 
    private readonly double _Value2;

    public string Id { get { return _Id; } } 
    public double Value1 { get { return _Value1; } } 
    public double Value2 { get { return _Value2; } }

    public MyTuple(string Id, double Value1, double Value2)
    {
        _Id = Id; 
        _Value1 = Value1; 
        _Value2 = Value2;    
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is MyTuple)
                return Equals((MyTuple)obj);
        return false;
    }

    public bool Equals(MyTuple obj)
    {
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (!EqualityComparer<string>.Default.Equals(_Id, obj._Id)) return false; 
        if (!EqualityComparer<double>.Default.Equals(_Value1, obj._Value1)) return false; 
        if (!EqualityComparer<double>.Default.Equals(_Value2, obj._Value2)) return false;    
        return true;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        int hash = 0;
        hash ^= EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(_Id); 
        hash ^= EqualityComparer<double>.Default.GetHashCode(_Value1); 
        hash ^= EqualityComparer<double>.Default.GetHashCode(_Value2);
        return hash;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("{{ Id = {0}, Value1 = {1}, Value2 = {2} }}", _Id, _Value1, _Value2);
    }
}
```

It's properly comparable and can be used in LINQ expressions.